# Is there a way for Windows 7 to support TLS 1.3 (.NET 4.8)

Tags: .net, windows-7, tls1.3

As far as I have read Win7 doesn't support TLS1.3, although there is rare information on this. Is there a way for Windows 7 to support TLS1.3, and if so how to do it?

I have coded my application in .NET 4.8 which supports TLS1.3, but Windows 7 still fails to establish connection.

Comment: Given that experimental support was only [recently added to Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1909), you expect for some reason that they'd have prioritised backporting it to an unsupported OS?

Comment: You can simply say no, instead of being condescending. I didn't specify **official** support, just asking if there is a way I am not aware of.